# Error on line 216139361?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, javascript

Just wondering.

Recently I started seeing fun JS errors in IE8.

> Syntax error
>   Line: 216139361
>   Symbol: 20
>   Code: 0

Or:

> Syntax error
>   Line: 216010057
>   Symbol: 20
>   Code: 0

They happen when a promotion for an area51 project appears to the right.
[image]

Doesn't hurt, doesn't seem to break anything. Just curious.

Comment: There's a certain Irony in the fact that it is "Bibilical Hermeneutics" which is breaking stackexchange, the site designed to generate answers to (the great?) questions

Comment: @brook Biblical Hermeneutics and all other area51 projects :)

Comment: Yep, that's a bug in Adzerk (the ad management software). We'll pass that on.

Comment: @balpha Does it indeed has 216 million lines of JS code?

Comment: @GSerg: Not quite :) IE gets very creative when making up line numbers for dynamically inserted JavaScript; I've seen that before.

Comment: hmm, might also be ours... we're looking at it, either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed late last week.  Thanks for the report.